# How to set a property of an existing and partially populated Struts 1 Bean in session, on 'onchange' event in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, session, onchange, struts-1

The scenario:
We are on a screen that has a text box. The value in text box could be populated from the VO which is a bean in the session. If there is no value saved in the database for this particular variable, than the text box is empty.

Desired behavior:
If the user enters text in the text box, and navigates to a different screen than returns, the text box should be populated with the text he entered before. The text should not be saved to the database until 'Save' button is clicked.

Comment: Edit: It is a requirement to store the temporary text in a bean property, no client side storage allowed.

Comment: Ajax submit each n seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Store your value in a cookie or local storage and repopulate from the cookie client side. No server side magic required.

In the onload event you should read the local storage and set it in the textbox there is a value stored.

```
window.onload = function(){
      var val = localStorage.getItem('value'); // or localStorage.value
      if(val != null)
          document.getElementById("myData").value = val;

}
```

In the onbeforeunload event you should retrieve the value of the textbox and save it in the local storage.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    localStorage.setItem('value', document.getElementById("myData").value); // or  localStorage.value = document.getElementById("myData").value
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that it is a requirement to store the temporary text in a bean property, no client side storage allowed.